# React and Stripe integration - client secret returned by Stripe not being recognised by React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, stripe-payments

I'm integrating Stripe in to my React SPA

I'ver created a Checkout component in my front end:

```
export default function Checkout() {

  const fetchClientSecret = useCallback(() => {
    // Create a Checkout Session
    fetch("/create-checkout-session", {
      method: "POST",
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => data.clientSecret);
  }, []);


  // Define options being passed to Stripe
  const options = {fetchClientSecret};
    
  return (
    <div>
      <EmbeddedCheckoutProvider stripe={stripePromise} options={options}>
        <EmbeddedCheckout />
      </EmbeddedCheckoutProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and a corresponding create-checkout-session endpoint in my Express back end

```
app.post('/create-checkout-session', async (req, res) => {

  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    ui_mode: 'embedded',
    line_items: [
      {
        price: 'price_1Oxtf42MrIfdvsrao10PzNxF',
        quantity: 1,
      },
    ],
    mode: 'payment',
    return_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}/thankyou?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
  });

  console.log(session.client_secret);
  
  res.send({clientSecret: session.client_secret});
});
```

The price ID I'm passing to stripe.checkout.sessions.create is correct. My console.log call confirms that the client secret is being correctly generated by the back end.

My problem is that Stripe is returning this when I call the Checkout conpionent:

```
Uncaught (in promise) IntegrationError: fetchClientSecret failed with error "The fetchClientSecret function should always resolve with a client secret as a string. The function that was provided resolved with a value type of undefined."
```

Can anyone help explain why this is happening, please?

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is of asynchronous API call. Currently, the `fetchClientSecret` function is returning `undefined` as there is no return statement and no awaiting for the API response.

You can declare the function with the `async` keyword and `await` for the API response.

The best way would be to use a state variable and set it with the client secret after successful response.

```
const [clientSecret, setClientSecret] = useState("");

const fetchClientSecret = useCallback(async () => {
    try{
        // Create a Checkout Session
        const res = await fetch("/create-checkout-session", {
            method: "POST",
        })

        const responseBody = await res.json();
        setClientSecret(responseBody.clientSecret)
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }

}, []);


 return (
    <div>
      {clientSecret?<EmbeddedCheckoutProvider stripe={stripePromise} options={{clientSecret: clientSecret}}>
        <EmbeddedCheckout />
      </EmbeddedCheckoutProvider>
      : <div>LOADING...</div>}
    </div>
  );
```